# Build 2 lists in one go while reading from file, pythonically

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I'm reading a big file with hundreds of thousands of number pairs representing the edges of a graph. I want to build 2 lists as I go: one with the forward edges and one with the reversed.

Currently I'm doing an explicit `for` loop, because I need to do some pre-processing on the lines I read. However, I'm wondering if there is a more pythonic approach to building those lists, like list comprehensions, etc.

But, as I have 2 lists, I don't see a way to populate them using comprehensions without reading the file twice.

My code right now is:

```
with open('SCC.txt') as data:
    for line in data:
        line = line.rstrip()
        if line:
            edge_list.append((int(line.rstrip().split()[0]), int(line.rstrip().split()[1])))
            reversed_edge_list.append((int(line.rstrip().split()[1]), int(line.rstrip().split()[0])))
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would keep your logic as it is the *Pythonic* approach just not *split/rstrip* the same line multiple times:

```
with open('SCC.txt') as data:
    for line in data:
        spl = line.split()
        if spl:
            i, j = map(int, spl)
            edge_list.append((i, j))
            reversed_edge_list.append((j, i))
```

Calling *rstrip* when you have already called it is  redundant in itself even more so when you are splitting as that would already remove the whitespace so splitting just once means you save doing a lot of unnecessary work.

You can also use *csv.reader* to read the data and filter empty rows once you have a single whitespace delimiting:

```
from csv import reader

with open('SCC.txt') as data:
    edge_list, reversed_edge_list = [], []
    for i, j in filter(None, reader(data, delimiter=" ")):
        i, j = int(i), int(j)
        edge_list.append((i, j))
        reversed_edge_list.append((j, i))
```

Or if there are multiple whitespaces delimiting you can use `map(str.split, data)`:

```
    for i, j in filter(None, map(str.split, data)):
        i, j = int(i), int(j)
```

Whatever you choose will be faster than going over the data twice or splitting the sames lines multiple times.

Comment: I'm actually doing the `rstrip()` to remove trailing `\r\n` characters in empty lines. Without it your code errors out with `i, j = map(int, spl)
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)`

Comment: @NickSlavsky, that sould have been `if spl`,  spl will be empty for any lines with just whitespace

Comment: whoops, didn't figure it out myself. Thank you! By the way, your solution turned out to be almost 2 times faster than my initial code with redundant splits.

Answer (score 5):

You *can't* create two lists in one comprehension, so, instead of doing the same operations twice on the two lists, one viable option would be to initialize one of them and then create the second one by reversing each entry in the first one. That way you don't iterate over the file twice.

To that end, you could create the first list `edge_list` with a comprehension (not sure why you called `rsplit` *again* on it):

```
edge_list = [tuple(map(int, line.split())) for line in data]
```

And now go through each entry and reverse it with `[::-1]` in order to create its reversed sibling `reverse_edge_list`.

*Using mock data* for `edge_list`:

```
edge_list = [(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]
```

Reversing it could look like this:

```
reverse_edge_list = [t[::-1] for t in edge_list]
```

Which now looks like:

```
reverse_edge_list
[(2, 1), (4, 3), (6, 5)]
```

Comment: I might suggest `[tuple(map(line.split())) ...]` which looks a little cleaner.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe not clearer, but shorter:

```
with open('SCC.txt') as data:
    process_line = lambda line, r: (int(line.rstrip().split()[r]), int(line.rstrip().split()[1-r]))

    edge_list, reverved_edge_list = map(list, zip(*[(process_line(line, 0), process_line(line, 1)) 
                                                    for line in data
                                                    if line.rstrip()]))
```

Comment: hey, did not ways your answer, was working in the same myself, +1

Answer (score 3):

Here comes a solution

A test file:

```
In[19]: f = ["{} {}".format(i,j) for i,j in zip(xrange(10), xrange(10, 20))]
In[20]: f
Out[20]: 
['0 10',
 '1 11',
 '2 12',
 '3 13',
 '4 14',
 '5 15',
 '6 16',
 '7 17',
 '8 18',
 '9 19']
```

One liner using comprehension, zip and map:

```
In[27]: l, l2 = map(list,zip(*[(tuple(map(int, x.split())), tuple(map(int, x.split()))[::-1]) for x in f]))
In[28]: l
Out[28]: 
[(0, 10),
 (1, 11),
 (2, 12),
 (3, 13),
 (4, 14),
 (5, 15),
 (6, 16),
 (7, 17),
 (8, 18),
 (9, 19)]
In[29]: l2
Out[29]: 
[(10, 0),
 (11, 1),
 (12, 2),
 (13, 3),
 (14, 4),
 (15, 5),
 (16, 6),
 (17, 7),
 (18, 8),
 (19, 9)]
```

Explaining, with `[(tuple(map(int, x.split())), tuple(map(int, x.split()))[::-1]) for x in f]` we build a list containing a pair tuple with the pair tuples and its reversed forms:

```
In[24]: [(tuple(map(int, x.split())), tuple(map(int, x.split()))[::-1]) for x in f]
Out[24]: 
[((0, 10), (10, 0)),
 ((1, 11), (11, 1)),
 ((2, 12), (12, 2)),
 ((3, 13), (13, 3)),
 ((4, 14), (14, 4)),
 ((5, 15), (15, 5)),
 ((6, 16), (16, 6)),
 ((7, 17), (17, 7)),
 ((8, 18), (18, 8)),
 ((9, 19), (19, 9))]
```

Applaying `zip` to the unpack form we split the tuples inside the main tuple, so we have 2 tuples containing the tuples pairs in the first and the reversed in the others:

```
In[25]: zip(*[(tuple(map(int, x.split())), tuple(map(int, x.split()))[::-1]) for x in f])
Out[25]: 
[((0, 10),
  (1, 11),
  (2, 12),
  (3, 13),
  (4, 14),
  (5, 15),
  (6, 16),
  (7, 17),
  (8, 18),
  (9, 19)),
 ((10, 0),
  (11, 1),
  (12, 2),
  (13, 3),
  (14, 4),
  (15, 5),
  (16, 6),
  (17, 7),
  (18, 8),
  (19, 9))]
```

Almost there, we just use `map` to transform that tuples into lists.

**EDIT:**
as @PadraicCunningham asked, for filtering empty lines, just add a `if x` in the comprehension `[ ... for x in f if x]`

Comment: Try it with a file with empty lines

Comment: just filter the empty lines with filter or in the comprehension @PadraicCunningham